# Hide parameter from url with .httacces file

Tags: php, .htaccess, parameters

I have url reader?id=12

I have hided php extension with following .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But I want it to look like this in address bar: **reader/12**

How should I modify .htaccess  file?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `%{QUERY_STRING}`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /reader/%1 [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Then to internally rewrite the URL back, also use:

```
RewriteRule ^/reader/([^/]*) /reader?id=$1 [L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this. You'll notice I've used `R=301`, this is a permanent redirection, while testing I advise you change this to `R=302` which is a temporary redirection.